# postscript: how to cut a string a certain width before show?

Tags: postscript, eps

I need to print a string till a certain width for example:

(abcd efgh) show
I need to print only 36 points of the string, in this case I want to print only abcd and half an e.
how can I do this?
or at least to print only till e or before e?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a clip. clip and rectclip will do 
the job. Remember to gsave and grestore because otherwise the clip will persist.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a partial 'e', use Ken's suggestion and use a clip.

To exclude the 'e' entirely, you can use `stringwidth`. This loop decreases the length of the string by 1 until it is less than the specified maximum.

```
/Times-Roman 14 selectfont

(abcd efgh) 36 {
    1 index stringwidth pop % s max len 
    2 copy ge {
        pop pop exit
    }{  
        pop  % s max 
        exch % max s
        0 1 index length 1 sub getinterval % max s[0:n-2]
        exch % s' max
    } ifelse
} loop

==
```

Output:

```
(abcd )
```

Comment: Thanks, but cutting the letter in the middle is exactly what I wanted.